# What does "wipe your chin and walk away" mean?

Tags: meaning, quotes

In the movie *The Social Network* Sean Parker says in his first meeting with Mark:

> Sean Parker: "And they want you to say 'thank you' while you, excuse me, wipe your chin and walk away."

I never was quite able to figure this one out , so what exactly does ***wipe your chin and walk away*** refers to?

If you wish, you can see to the YouTube clip of the conversation   [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dU6scly2AFU#t=31).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible meanings for the phrase. The basic concept is that you've been wronged but you're supposed to be thankful for the chance to be wronged by the person.

The more likely candidate is that you are on the giving end of male oral sex but supposed to be thankful for it. See for instance here: http://www.screenit.com/movies/2010/the_social_network.html

The less likely candidate is that they punch you in the lip, so your lip is bleeding, but you are supposed to thank them for that. I can't find any support for this interpretation.

Comment: The first example is the correct one. The second is not, no one ever says that.

Comment: That said, in a different example, it could mean eat your fill, wipe your chin and walk away. Meaning:  Just take what you came for and leave.  Don't dare come back for more.   I've seen this usage, too. But in this case the first example above is the correct interpretation.

Comment: @DavidM, I wouldn't call what I supply two *examples*. I would call them two possible *interpretations*. I've definitely heard *wipe your chin* by itself as an account of taking a hit such that there's blood on your chin, so I do think it's a possible (but highly unlikely) meaning for the whole expression.

Comment: Fair enough. Interpretations. But, I've never heard anyone say thank you, wipe the blood off of their chin and walk away.

Comment: There's absolutely no question of any other interpretation in this context. Supporting evidence for which includes the fact that Parker prefaces it by "excuse me" (i.e. - please forgive the crude expression I'm about to use), and that the camera immediately cuts to show the girl opposite looking down in embarrassment.

Answer (score -6):

To wipe one's mouth is actually biblical from proverbs..it means to cut yourself off from the subject discussed...I wipe my mouth of it and will never have anything to do with that again..
Brija

Comment: Evidence? Citation? I'm familiar with the concept of disassociating yourself from a decision taken, to [wash your hands off something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wash-your-hands-of-someone-or-something) or someone  (i.e. Pontius Pilate)  and shaking the [dust  off your feet](https://www.gotquestions.org/shake-dust-off-feet.html). But wiping your mouth?